# why showing that $\mathcal{R} \cong \mathbb{C}$ as rings implies that $\mathcal{R}$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

Here is the question:

Define $E \in GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ by $E = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ and let $\mathcal{R} = \{aI + bE| a,b \in \mathbb{R}\} \subset M_{2}(\mathbb{R}).$

$(a)$ Show that $\mathcal{R} \cong \mathbb{C}$ as rings (so $\mathcal{R}$ is a field). Which matrices correspond to the subgroup $S^{1} \subset \mathbb{C}^{*}$?

**My question is:**

I know how to answer the question. The only thing that I do not understand is: why showing that  $\mathcal{R} \cong \mathbb{C}$ as rings implies that $\mathcal{R}$ is a field?

Could anyone explain this for me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A field is a ring in which every non-zero element has a multiplicative inverse. An isomorphism preserves this property since if $xy = 1$ one has $\phi(x)\phi(y) = 1$.

Comment: Should not the ring be commutative also?

Comment: @Smart20 ah sorry, different definitions of "ring." but if two rings are isomorphic, one is commutative iff the other is, since $xy = yx \Rightarrow \phi(x)\phi(y) = \phi(y)\phi(x)$.

Comment: I mean in the definition of a field the ring should be commutative also. Are you saying that  the ring $\mathcal{R}$ is commutative?

Answer (score 2):

The definition of ismorphism, is that these two objects preserve estructural properties, and be a field is a estructural property.
Also remember that a ismorphism between two rings is a aplication that is one to one and onto, so too preserves the operation.